# Unable to dynamically transpile ES module System.config({ transpile: 'transpile-module'})

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It's my tsconfig.js

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "built",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": false
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules"
]
```

}

i'm transpiling my 'hello-angular.ts' into 'hello-angular.js' using `tsc` command. And import by `System.import ('built/hello-angular')`

When im starting server i've got err in browser 
`Unable to dynamically transpile ES module A loader plugin needs to be configured via`SystemJS.config({ transpiler: 'transpiler-module' })``

I'm dont understand, why systemjs trying to transpile es5 file.. I was set system.config({transpiler: false}) , but it didnt help..

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a transpiler as noted in the following answer:

[Angular 2 - Unable to dynamically transpile ES module, angular2-google-map-auto-complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45605805/angular-2-unable-to-dynamically-transpile-es-module-angular2-google-map-auto)

In mine it looks like this in systemjs.config.js:

```
map: {
  'plugin-babel': 'npm:systemjs-plugin-babel/plugin-babel.js',
  'systemjs-babel-build': 'npm:systemjs-plugin-babel/systemjs-babel-browser.js'
},
transpiler: 'plugin-babel',
```

Comment: I've added these configuration the transpiler error  goes away, but another error appears which is  "Cannot add property test-plugin, object is not extensible" in console

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in your tsconfig.json:

```
"module": "commonjs",
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error on one of the plugins:

Error: Unable to dynamically transpile ES module
   A loader plugin needs to be configured via `SystemJS.config({ transpiler: 'transpiler-module' })`.
  Instantiating http://localhost:62362/node_modules/angular-star-rating/index.js

Resolved this error by replacing this line in systemjs.config.js:

```
'angular-star-rating': { defaultExtension: 'js', main: 'index.js' }
```

with this line:

```
'angular-star-rating': { defaultExtension: 'js', main: 'angular-star-rating.umd.js' }
```