# Angular 2 - Unable to dynamically transpile ES module, angular2-google-map-auto-complete

Tags: angular

Iam working on an angular project. Iam using angular2-google-map-auto-complete module for the google location auto complete feature.
For this i have included below lines in Systemjs.config.js

```
            var map ={ 'angular2-google-map-auto-complete' : 'node_modules/angular2-google-map-auto-complete'};
            var packages = {'angular2-google-map-auto-complete' : {defaultExtension:'js'}};
```

But on starting the npm server iam getting the following error on console.

```
Error: Unable to dynamically transpile ES module
   A loader plugin needs to be configured via `SystemJS.config({ transpiler: 'transpiler-module' })`.
  Instantiating http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2-google-map-auto-complete/directives/googleplace.directive.js
  Loading http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
  Loading main.js
    at transpile (instantiate.js:463)
    at instantiate.js:241
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:365)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:125)
    at zone.js:760
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:165)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:593)
    at <anonymous>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a research i found the solution. I just installed the babel plugin.

```
npm i systemjs-plugin-babel
```

And then updated the systemjs.config.js file.

```
SystemJS.config({
  map: {
    'plugin-babel': 'path/to/systemjs-plugin-babel/plugin-babel.js',
    'systemjs-babel-build': 'path/to/systemjs-plugin-babel/systemjs-babel-browser.js'
  },
  transpiler: 'plugin-babel'
});
```

Restarted the npm and its working.